# How can i make date as primary autoincrement

Tags: vb.net, primary-key

I want my primary key to be a date plus an auto incremented id (ie "20151013 & ID").

How can I increment the ID together with the date as my primary key? Is it possible to increment only the ID but not the date? I'm using VB.net.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad design idea. Your primary key should be an auto increment (identity) integer or long. If you need the ID and the date concatenated together for some reason, then do it on the VB.Net side:

```
myRow = GetRowFromDatabase() ' Fetch Row
Dim dateAndId As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", myRow.Date, myRow.Id)
```

SQL Server (and most other databases) are not going to autoincrement a field unless its a whole number field, such as 'Integer', 'Long', 'Short', etc. If you absolutely need this functionality in a database, then consider making a view with a 'SELECT' statement similar to this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MyDate, 101) + CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS MyIdDateField,  
* FROM MyTable
```